# Is that possible to reorder tabs in ConEmu?

Tags: conemu

ConEmu is a great tool I discovered recently.
I was just wondering if it's possible to reorder tabs in ConEmu?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Build 140703 introduce reordering by mouse dragging.

Also, by default, <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> hotkeys do reordering.

Of course, you may redefine any suitable combo on "Keys & Macro" settings page, search for "Move active tab leftward" and "Move active tab rightward".

Comment: Great, thanks! That works. I guess it's just not something immediately obvious, like if you would drag&drop or in the right-click-menu on the tab.

Comment: Yeah, drag-and-drop would be a great feature.

Comment: Good to know the author is on here! ConEmu is great :)

Comment: The tab ordering does not seem to save for me after restarting - does this happen for any one else and, if so, does anyone have a solution?