# Is it possible to re-order Cygwin tabs in Conemu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cygwin, tabs, conemu

I can re-order 'cmd' tabs in Conemu ( as per [Is that possible to reorder tabs in ConEmu?](https://superuser.com/questions/623938/is-that-possible-to-reorder-tabs-in-conemu)), but the <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> shortcuts do not work if the tab has a Cygwin shell in it.

I have tried various combinations of hotkey modifiers but none of them seem to work with the Cygwin shell.

This is problematic because most of the tabs in my ConEmu have Cygwin shells.

I open a Cygwin shell using the following command:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin shell is **sh.exe**!

mintty.exe is another GUI terminal emulator, but not a shell. Are you sure you need it?

When you run GUI application in ConEmu - it put keyboard focus into that child window and does not process keystrokes at all. With the exception of very few globally registered keystrokes.

If you open "Keys & Macro" settings page you may find global hotkey for "Put focus to ConEmu window" (not sure of the exact name). After that you may reorder GUI child applications running in ConEmu tabs.

**Upd**. New ConEmu builds can reorder tabs by dragging them with mouse.

Comment: That works. Cheers !!

Comment: The hotkey is "Set focus to child GUI application". In my case it was Win+Z.

Answer (score 3):

Maximus' answer (both options are correct). I'll quickly jot down a few details (adding this as an answer to use snapshots).

#### Option 1 : If you use mintty or another terminal emulator

In Settings -> 'Keys & Macro', add a keyboard snapshot for 'Set focus to ConEmu' like so:

[image]

Once you do this, you should be able to use this shortcut to focus Conemu and then use the shortcut to re-order.

For example, my shortcuts are setup as in the snapshot:
'Set focus to ConEmu' : <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
'Move active tab leftward' : <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left</kbd>

So if I have to move a mintty console left/right I use the above in sequence.

This is a generic way of re-orderding tabs if you use ConEmu to run GUI applications.

#### Option 2 (Simpler, Cygwin Specific): Directly use bash.exe/sh.exe

If I start a new console by directly using the bash or sh.exe, then I can re-order without any issues (there is not need to focus the Conemu window first)

For instance:

```
C:\dev\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

[image]